# Do Heroku dyno's affect external API calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, autoscaling

I have an app that makes hundreds of thousands of calls to external APIs (via HTTP requests) each day.

Does the number of web dynos I have on my Heroku app affect the speed or number of calls I can make per second, or the ability to save the data retrieved?

Comment: How are you making the calls? Inside of a web-request? Or via a rake task?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Rake task.

Answer (score 1):

No, your rake tasks will not slow down your web-dynos. Nor will your web dynos have an effect on your rake tasks. They run in separate processes (a dyno).

Heroku will end up billing you for your rake tasks though. (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing)

> One-off dynos
>
> When executing a one-off dyno with heroku run, a dyno will be
>   provisioned for your command, and the time spent executing the command
>   will accrue usage.